# SQL in clause, on column, doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, list, where-clause

I have a table named 'product' which has a column named 'id_subcategory'.
This column contains list of numbers separated by comma.

The problem is this query find the 91 number only if it's the first in list. Otherwise returns 0. And it is not ok.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product WHERE 91 IN (id_subcategory);
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should normalize your data model and get rid of the comma-delimited list of values.

Comment: Look SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product WHERE id_subcategory LIKE '%,91,%';

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample

Comment: @Roy, id_subcategory is the column. I want to see if my value is in it.

Comment: @ValentinTanasescu, do you know how SQL work? WHERE column LIKE '%YOUR-VALUE%' is the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `WHERE ',' || id_subcategory || ',' LIKE '%,91,%'`

This isn't going to use indexes because of the leading `%`, so you should consider not storing comma separated lists if you will need to query the subcategories often.

Comment: Yes agree, sounds like the ids should be in a separate table.

Comment: This might return false positives, e.g. 991, should be `WHERE ',' || id_subcategory || ',' LIKE '%,91,%'`

Comment: What does WHERE ',' means?

Comment: @ValentinTanasescu This adds a comma to the start and the end of the list, then looks for `,91,` specifically (to avoid false positives like 991).  If there is spacing between the list items it will need to be adjusted, but that is the concept.